# Bulk scan of family photo album

Tags: photography, scanning, catalog

Looking for a piece of software that would help digitising a family album of many hundreds of photos. Requirements are as few manual work as possible. Mostly what I want is for software to crop photos properly, easy rescanning and saving to loseless format.

Tried to do so with photo editing software and it’s a nightmare bcs of the need to do repetitive actions on each photo.

**Target OS** is Windows. It’s ok for it to be a paid piece of software up to $25 (or more for a reason).

Comment: What OS must it run on, and how much you'd be willing to spend if it came to paid software?

Comment: FYI:  As a person who has scanned many (many) 1000's of pages/photos, a document scanner which will definitely cost more and isn't software.  Depending on the thickness of the photos you can place 10-50 in the input bin and just wait for them to finish.  Save to PNG or TIFF no problem.  Mine has a software deskew option.  Also cropping isn't a problem, and neither is double side.  It detects the size of the physical photo and can duplex scan in a single pass.

Comment: FYI: document scanners don't have the resolution DPI for negatives.  Sure you can probably get ok scan, but nothing more.  Although do you care about archivist quality scans?

Comment: @cybernard I have photoprints and not negatives. So it's ok for me to have standart 600dpi of a mid-price document scanner :)

Comment: @DenisKulagin  Then its seems like an obvious choice as many can do 600dpi.  I have an epson ES-400 in case your researching different brands.  Plus most stores offer a 30 day return policy, in case one particular device doesn't work out for you.